# What is the reason not all value types are nullable?

Tags: .net, nullable

Is there any penalty, such that you should only set them as nullable when you really need it?

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Various reasons:

- History: `Nullable<T>` didn't exist until .NET 2.0, and it can't break existing code - especially with the different boxing rules for `Nullable<T>`
- Meaning: if I want an `int`, I might not **want** it to be nullable... I want it to be an `int`, and I don't want to have to check-for/handle nulls
- Space: it adds extra cost to each struct... in particular, imagine a `byte[]`, and now consider if `byte` was nullable - lots of extra overhead; *plus it would stop you doing ***blits*** etc*
- Performance: `Nullable<T>` adds lots of extra penalties; in particular lots of hidden calls to `.HasValue` and `.Value` / `.GetValueOrDefault()`; this is shown in particular in the "lifted operators" - i.e. `x + y` becomes something like below, which adds up for tight loops etc:

  `(x.HasValue && y.HasValue) ? (x.GetValueOrDefault() + y.GetValueOrDefault()) : null`

Likewise, `x == y` has to check:

- if both null => true
- if one null => false
- otherwise use `==` on `GetValueOrDefault()` of each

**lots** of overhead....

Comment: Don't forget about the extra ?? operator they threw in as well.
int i = j ?? k;  // if j is null, use k.

Comment: well, that isn't specific to `Nullable<T>` - but another good point

Comment: @Chris does that work at all? j can't be null, else you can't assign it to a value type, right? ;-)

Comment: @Erik - it can if `j` is nullable (i.e. `int?`) and `k` is non-nullable (i.e. `int`)

Comment: And you will be screwed if you use ReferenceEquals!

Comment: @leppie - that stands for any (unboxed) value-type, though

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is a penalty. The `Nullable<T>` structure contain the value and also a boolean flag that determines the nullness of the value.

Although the boolean is only one byte, structures are aligned to even word boundaries. An `int` uses four bytes of memory, but an `int?` needs eight bytes.

Comment: The penalty is much worse than an extra word.  The design of the nullable structure means that creating a `Nullable<T>` will require at least one extra "copy T" operation, and any code which receives a `Nullable<T>` will have to perform at least one extra "copy T" operation in order to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Which value types are actually nullable? I know of none.

EDIT: If you refer to the string type, then it is not a value type, but a reference type.

Comment: You need to wrap them in the Nullable<T> type

Comment: But that's something different then. I believe the topic starter meant value types nullable out of the box, probably referring to string type.

Comment: I think the OP means something like "if value types can be made nullable, why aren't they all nullable from start?".

Comment: Well, lots of programmers cannot grasp the concepts of pointers and recursions, many would probably be confused if types were all nullable from the start. Nullable<T> is for advanced classes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Marc Gravell answer, check the reflected code from Nullable<T>:

```
public struct Nullable&lt;T&gt; where T: struct
{
    private bool hasValue;

    internal T value;

    public Nullable(T value)
    {
        this.value = value;
        this.hasValue = true;
    }

    public bool HasValue
    {
        get
        {
            return this.hasValue;
        }
    }
    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            if (!this.HasValue)
            {
                ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource.InvalidOperation_NoValue);
            }
            return this.value;
        }
    }
    public T GetValueOrDefault()
    {
        return this.value;
    }

    public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
    {
        if (!this.HasValue)
        {
            return defaultValue;
        }
        return this.value;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!this.HasValue)
        {
            return (other == null);
        }
        if (other == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return this.value.Equals(other);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (!this.HasValue)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return this.value.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        if (!this.HasValue)
        {
            return "";
        }
        return this.value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator T?(T value)
    {
        return new T?(value);
    }

    public static explicit operator T(T? value)
    {
        return value.Value;
    }
}
```

You'll notice the existence of the boolean `HasValue` and how the properties use it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the implementation. An integer in C# is defined as

```
public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible, IComparable<int>, IEquatable<int>
```

A struct is stored directly on the stack, as opposed to objects references which are pointers to memory (the reference itself is in the stack, but the allocation is in the stack).

A NULL reference simply means that the pointer in the stack hasn't been initialized to a location in the heap.